# Se puede realizar algo contra el voto serial negativo

Tags: discusión

el día de hoy al entrar a SO me percate de varios -1 es un poco extraños que tenga varios -1 en varias preguntas al mismo tiempo, , me llamo la atención y recordé que hace tiempo reporte lo mismo en SO en ingles, resulta que un mismo usuario voto en serie negativamente, al final solo supe que se le hizo saber a este usuario sobre esto y eliminaron los votos negativos, puede ser esto posible aquí, si se detecta voto serial de un usuario?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Coincidencia o no, estas son las últimas respuestas he realizado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas son mis ultimas respuestas

[Poner una palabra en negrita en un texto XML](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48970/poner-una-palabra-en-negrita-en-un-texto-xml/48995#48995)

[Problemas al Borrar Alarma](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44723/problemas-al-borrar-alarma/48914#48914)

[Seleccionar un valor por defecto en un elemento HTML <select> cuya opción está deshabilitada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48900/problema-con-disable-select/48901#48901)

[Insertar ruta con espacios en visual basic](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48865/insertar-ruta-con-espacios-en-visual-basic/48887#48887)

[Exception in thread "Loading Sources" al iniciar Android SDK Manager](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48971/exception-in-thread-loading-sources-al-iniciar-android-sdk-manager/48998#48998)

[Visual Studio 2010 no corre el proyecto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48626/visual-studio-2010-no-corre-el-proyecto/48663#48663)

Aclaro, **no estoy en contra del voto negativo, mi pregunta es relacionada a una actitud que se puede dar en SO**, saludos.

Comment: Claramente es algún usuario enojado (cosas que pasan, no veo que haya mucho más que discutir)... Quizás es para dejar sólo [soporte] y eliminar [discusión]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Respuesta corta

El sistema de los sitios de Stack Exchange ya incluye un algoritmo para detectar y corregir esto sin necestidad de que sea reportado por los usuarios. Espera 36 horas y en caso de que ocurra la correción, has el reporte.

## Respuesta en SE

> That's serial downvoting.
>
> There are three ways to fix it:
>
> 1. Do NOTHING. The daily vote anomaly script will pick it up and your rep will be recalculated automatically.
> 2. If after 36 hours (give the script time to run) you still see a problem, then flag one of your posts and ask a moderator to look into
>      the anomalous voting patterns.
> 3. If it still hasn't been corrected, contact the SE team via the "contact us" link at the bottom of any page on the site.

## Referencias

[What can I do if I'm the victim of serial downvoting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/)

Comment: Cuidado. Ante casos similares, en lugar de responder, votar a cierre como duplicado de http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/663/227 (la has puesto en tu pregunta de faq de faqs)