# Recibí notificación de comentario a mi respuesta en pregunta eliminada pero no puedo ver el comentario completo

Tags: bug, estado-completado

## Resumen

1. Bug<sup>1</sup>: El enlace a respuesta eliminada en la página de respuestas eliminadas en el perfil del usuario lleva a la pregunta no a la respuesta
2. Bug<sup>1</sup>: El URL a respuesta eliminada en cascada<sup>2</sup> devuelve error 404 página no encontrada.

NOTAS:

- <sup>1</sup>: Le llamé bug a una característica que no funciona como me parece que es lógico esperar que funcione.
- <sup>2</sup>: Por respuesta eliminada en cascada me refiero a que la respuesta no está disponible porque la pregunta fue eliminada, no la respuesta en sí.

## Original

El día de ayer publiqué una respuesta a una pregunta en Meta que fue eliminada ayer mismo. Recien recibí una notificación de un [comentario](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/3796?noredirect=1) pero no es posible verlo completo, ya que se muestra la página de error 404, no se encontró la página.

[image]

Me parece que el sistema debería avisar al "comentador", quien seguramente tiene privilegios para ver publicaciones eliminadas que no todos los notificados podrán ver el comentario.

## Actualización

### 20170216

Cree una nueva pregunta en meta específica para la solicitud de característica y eliminé la misma de esta publicación.

### 20170214

Cambie el orden de las actualizaciones de la mas reciente a la mas antigua. Próximamente separaré los bugs de la solicitud de característica, porque según me dicen, esta publicación está muy confusa :D

### 20170213.3

Recién me doy cuenta que el enlace apunta a la pregunta no a la respuesta eliminada... ¡Que alguien me explique!

[image: que alguien me explique hansito]

### 20170213.2

Recien encontré [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/)  donde me dió la pista sobre donde buscar, la parte inferior de la página perfil-actividad-respuestas

[image]

la cual me llevó a

[image]

pero [el enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1404/se-puede-realizar-algo-contra-el-voto-serial-negativo/1405#1405) ahí incluido continua devolviendo error 404 página no encontrada

### 20170213.1

Conversando/investigando sobre el tema averiguamos lo siguiente:

1. De acuerdo a [una respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161196/289691) a [How long can you see your own deleted answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161193/)  el autor de las respuestas eliminadas debería poder acceder a ellas, pero para ello debería haber guardado el enlace a la respuesta, pues a los pocos minutos se elimina de su perfil-actividad

   - Se probaron los enlaces indicados a continuación, ambos redirigen:

     - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1405/227
     - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1405/
2. El url facilitado por un usuario con privilegios para ver publicaciones eliminadas me redirige al URL de la pregunta el cual me muestra error 404, página no encontrada.

Comment: Eso es extraño. Es tu publicación, así que deberías poder ver todos los comentarios en ella.

Comment: Bueno, en este caso yo puse el comentario para que consideres usar las preguntas del faq y no reinventar la pólvora.

Comment: Gracias @LuiggiMendoza. Supongo que es "obvio" que no recordaba haber leído una pregunta del FAQ sobre eso, si la pregunta continuase disponible, podría marcarse como duplicada aún después de recibir respuestas. Lamentablemente la pregunta en cuestión fue eliminada.

Comment: Por cierto, tampoco recuerdo cómo ver una respuesta propia asociada a una pregunta que fue elimanada.

Comment: Eso me parece más raro porque fuiste quien armó la lista inicial de faq :) pero nada, son cosas que pasan. Solo lo decía para ver si ya se encuentra allí o sino aprovechar en traducir algo para nuestro faq.

Comment: jaja, no porque haya armado la lista de FAQ leí todos los [meta-tag:faq]. Reconozco que debería haberlo hecho, perdón.

Comment: Creo que eso es tema de privilegios. Específicamente, el privilegio de [Acceso a Herramientas de Moderación](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), que de momento se logra con 2000 puntos.

Comment: Pregunta en [meta.se] sobre ver las repuestas propias -> http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229621/cant-see-my-own-deleted-answer-anymore-after-question-is-moderator-deleted. Leyendo detenidamente

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53557/discussion-between-ruben-and-luiggi-mendoza).

Comment: El "comentador" sólo pudo dejar un comentario porque es un moderador. El resto de los mortales no podemos dejar comentarios en publicaciones eliminadas... Si es una propuesta, recomendaría obviar la parte del comentario, centrándote en la parte de "visualizarla"

Comment: Es un reporte de dos "bugs" (desde mi punto de vista) y una propuesta. De acuerdo que podría parecer confuso, pero podría decirse que es porque SOes, de hecho SE, es confuso. Tengo la intención de darme tiempo de separar el reporte de "bugs" de la propuesta. Esto será "algún día".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto fue solucionado (*[View *my* deleted question and answer with less than 10K](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125828/304899)*).

Lo describo en detalle en [Habilitar a usuarios con rep < 2000 ver respuestas propias que fueron eliminadas por la eliminación de la pregunta por su autor](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1413/127).