# Habilitar a usuarios con rep < 2000 ver respuestas propias que fueron eliminadas por la eliminación de la pregunta por su autor

Tags: característica-nueva, estado-completado, respuestas-borradas

**Solicitud de característica:** Habilitar a usuarios con rep < 2000 ver respuestas propias que fueron eliminadas por la eliminación de la pregunta por su autor, **o en su defecto**, avisar a los usuarios *con privilegios de ver publicaciones eliminadas* que los comentarios que realicen en las publicaciones eliminadas no podrán ser vistos por los notificados que *no tienen los privilegios para ver publicaciones eliminadas*, al menos mientras SOes siga mostrando error a un usuario sin el privilegio de ver publicaciones eliminadas, en particulara las propias.

Lo anterior es debido a que  a los usuarios con rep <2000 el enlace en respuestas eliminadas apunta a la pregunta, no a la respuesta. Por otro lado, el URL a la respuesta redirige a la pregunta. Al autor de la respuesta, cuando no es el autor de la pregunta se le muestra error 404.

Ejemplo:

1. Publiqué una respuesta a esta pregunta.
2. Fuí a https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/65 (gracias fedorqui)
3. Hice clic con el obtón derecho sobre el enlace y copie el URL, el cual es [Habilitar a usuarios con rep < 2000 ver respuestas propias que fueron eliminadas por la eliminación de la pregunta por su autor](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1413/habilitar-a-usuarios-con-rep-2000-ver-su-propias-respuestas-eliminadas/1415#1415)

Nótese que es un URL que apunta a la pregunta con "un ancla" (lenguage MS Word) a la respuesta, o sea, en este caso puedo acceder a la respuesta eliminada pues por ser el autor de la pregunta puedo acceder a la misma.

El problema al que me refiero en esta pregunta es que siendo un usuario con rep < 2000 no puedo acceder a una resputas a una pregunta que fue eliminada por su autor. Caso específico https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1404/se-puede-realizar-algo-contra-el-voto-serial-negativo/1405#1405 me devuelve error 404.

---

> ACTUALIZACION 2018/04/06: Ahora que tengo rep +2k si puedo ver la respuesta

---

**Pregunta relacionada:** [Recibí notificación de comentario a mi respuesta en pregunta eliminada pero no puedo ver el comentario completo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1407/)

**Artículo de Ayuda-Privilegios relacionado:** [Acceso A Herramientas De Moderación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)

Publicaciones relacionadas en Stack Overflow (en inglés, gracias [fedorqui](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/83/fedorqui)):

- [Can't access my own answer on a deleted question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287028/1983854)
- [Let me see the source of my own answers that have been deleted, please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287032/1983854)
- [Grant access to deleted singleton-answer & question also to <10K rep answerers when question is deleted by owner](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313870/1983854)

Comment: para ver tus respuestas o preguntas eliminadas puedes ir tu lista de PyR y abajo hay un link: `preguntas recientes eliminadas` o `respuestas recientes eliminadas`

Comment: En el caso de las respuestas no funciona para usuarios con rep <2000 ya  que el enlace apunta a la pregunta, no a la respuesta, además el URL a la respuesta redirige a la pregunta y este muestra error 404. Por favor, revisa la pregunta relacionada.

Comment: pues es un caso particular... porque normalmente (no importa la reputación que tengas) puedes ver tus RoP *recien* eliminadas...

Comment: ¿Conoces algún usuario con rep < 2000 que si pueda?

Comment: Rubén: vi un momento que publicabas una respuesta para probar. ¿Te funciona bien el enlace en http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/65 ?

Comment: En enlace en la página referida apunta a http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1413/habilitar-a-usuarios-con-rep-2000-ver-su-propias-respuestas-eliminadas/1415#1415. Come verás es un enlace a la pregunta con "un ancla" (lenguage MS Word) a la respuesta, o sea, para acceder a la respuesta eliminada debes poder acceder a la pregunta. El problema es que con rep < 2000 no se puede acceder a las publicaciones de otro que han sido eliminadas.

Comment: Tienes razón, ahora entiendo. Esto es [estado-por-diseño]: [Can't access my own answer on a deleted question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287028/1983854). Es decir, si no puedes ver preguntas eliminadas, no podrás tus respuestas en ella. No veo que haya tenido mucho recorrido la petición [Let me see the source of my own answers that have been deleted, please](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287032/1983854) y creo que sí sería bueno. Resumiendo: +1, tienes razón en que actualmente es un poco lioso y debería mejorarse.

Comment: Veo que sí tuvo mucho soporte [Grant access to deleted singleton-answer & question also to <10K rep answerers when question is deleted by owner](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313870/1983854). A ver si hay novedades al respecto.

Comment: Muchas gracias pro los enlaces. Ya los he agregado como publicaciones relacionadas.

Comment: Ahora entiendo: `acceder a una respuesta (propia) a una pregunta que fue eliminada por su autor` quizás sería ese el titulo adecuado a tu petición

Comment: Gracias aldanux. Voy a dejar "reposar" un rato la pregunta a ver si luego de tomar café, entre otras cosas, " se ve" esto mas claro. Por lo pronto , se me ocurre que la implementación técnica de esto implica tener una página para visualizar las respuestas que sea independiente de la pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desde el 22/3/17 los autores de *respuestas* a preguntas eliminadas pueden ver sus respuestas, gracias a [Konamiman](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/23/konamiman) y [Nick Craver](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/135201/nick-craver).

Fuente: [*View *my* deleted question and answer with less than 10K*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179511/304899).

---

#### Cómo ver tus respuestas eliminadas <sub><sup>(*[fuente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297922/304899))</sup></sub>

1. Ir a tu perfil y dentro de la pestaña de *Actividad*, seleccionar la pestaña **[*respuestas*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=answers)**.
   [image: tab respuestas]
2. Al final de la lista de tus respuestas, seleccionar *respuestas recientes eliminadas*.
   [image: respuestas recientes eliminadas]
   o simplemente se puede ir directo a:

   ```
   https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/<tu-id>
   ```

Ahí vas a poder ver la lista de tus respuestas eliminadas en los últimos 60 días.

3. Seleccionar la respuesta te lleva a la página, donde vas a poder verla.

   [image: Tu respuesta]

Notas:

- Los usuarios con [menos de 10K](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) no pueden ver otras respuestas, solamente la pregunta y la respuesta propia.
- Las respuestas a preguntas eliminadas de más de [60 días](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185492/304899) no van a aparecer listadas en la página de *respuestas recientes eliminadas*, aunque siguen siendo accesibles directamente con el enlace (si es que lo guardaste).

---

Respecto al tema de los comentarios:

> avisar a los usuarios con privilegios de ver publicaciones eliminadas que los comentarios que realicen en las publicaciones eliminadas no podrán ser vistos

Los usuarios ***no pueden*** comentar en publicaciones eliminadas, solamente un moderador puede. Se supone que un moderador sabe cómo funcionan [las menciones en comentarios](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1357/127), aunque a veces el comportamiento puede ser un poco complicado de recordar y pueden *meter la pata*. Lo que los moderadores comentan en una respuesta eliminada solo llega a su propietario en forma de notificación si:

1. Lo escribe el moderador que lo borró y
2. Lo hace en la primera hora desde que se borró. Fuente [*How do notifications on deleted posts work?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231668/209901).

<sup><sub>* Gracias [@fedorqui](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/83/fedorqui) por recordarme esto último.</sub></sup>

Comment: Además, lo que los moderadores escriben en una respuesta eliminada solo llega a su propietario en forma de notificación si: 1. Lo escribe el moderador que lo borró y 2. Lo hace en la primera hora desde que se borró. De [How do notifications on deleted posts work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231668/209901).