# ¿Por qué las preguntas se pueden eliminar aún si se está creando una respuesta?

Tags: discusión, eliminación-de-preguntas

Estaba *creando* la respuesta de una reciente pregunta, y de un momento a otro se eliminó la pregunta y mi intento de responder se convirtió en pérdida de tiempo.

¿No debería impedirse la eliminación de la pregunta mientras alguien esté creando una respuesta?

Nota: Ese "*no debería*" es tan sólo una observación, para aquellos que son *sensibles* al contexto.

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si se le impide borrar la pregunta porque un usuario está escribiendo una respuesta y ese usuario deja de escribir y la deja como borrador o no la publica nunca? ¿esa pregunta sería imborrable?

Comment: Se bloquea la eliminación cuando tiene votos positivos o alguna respuesta ya publicada ... No creo que detectar que alguien está respondiendo sea apropiado porque, por ejemplo yo personalmente, muchas veces copio el codigo de la pregunta a la respuesta y me pongo a toquetear intentando a veces dar con la solucion pero muchas veces no llegando a nada. Seria inapropiado no dejarle eliminarla solo porque alguien está *jugueteando* en la seccion de respuestas

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro el que la respuesta quedara en borrador sería una excepción, podría borrarse la pregunta de todos modos. Digo la respuestá que se está creando en ese momento.

Comment: Comprendo que es un inconveniente y fastidia mucho (me ha pasado varias veces), pero el derecho a publicar mi respuesta no puede pisar el derecho del usuario a borrar su pregunta.

Comment: Quizás sería interesante que hubiera un sistema que avisara al usuario antes de borrar (algo en plan "Hay X usuarios escribiendo respuestas, ¿estás seguro que quieres eliminar?") como se avisa al usuario que está editando de que se ha completado otra edición o que la pregunta ha sido editada/borrada.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro se podría proponer en [Meta.SE] pero lo malo es que no van a hacerlo para nosotros. Seria primero en [SO] si eso y luego aquí.

Comment: Me sorprendería que nadie lo hubiera sugerido ya

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro grandiosa idea, quedaría perfecto! :) Y sí, es mal que primero deba implementarse en la principal para luego hacer push a todos los children :v

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro: Efectivamente alguien ya lo sugirió [May I suggest: Are you sure you want to delete? Someone's answering the question right now. Give them 5 minutes to finish](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114170/289691)

Comment: @Rubén en la respuesta de ese link que comentaste hay un problemita y es que sí existe el bloqueo contra eliminación de preguntas (claro, por parte del que pregunta), cuando alguien ya ha respondido, no es posible eliminar la pregunta. Entonces eso de que el que pregunta debe tener la posibilidad de eliminar la pregunta es condicional.

Comment: @MáximaAlekz Esa respuesta es del 2011 y el que sea una respuesta aceptada sólo indica que el OP la aceptó, nada más.

Comment: @MáximaAlekz no se impide eliminar cuando alguien respondió, sino cuando hay un voto a favor en una respuesta, una aceptada, una recompensa o múltiples respuestas (tampoco se impide cuando haya un +1 en la pregunta).

Answer (score 3):

No solamente con borradores. Incluso si hubieras publicado tu respuesta, el autor de la pregunta tiene todo el derecho eliminarla.

- Las condiciones que le impedirían eliminarla (voto en respuesta, aceptación, recompensa o múltiples respuestas) están en [¿Cómo funciona la eliminación de publicaciones? ¿Por qué podría eliminarse una publicación y qué implica? ¿Cuál es el criterio para eliminar?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1033/127)

Me pasó algunas veces y da bronca, pero la decisión es, y tiene que ser, del autor de la pregunta. Es su decisión.

Si era una respuesta interesante (no duplicada), publicala haciendo la pregunta y la respuesta. Podrías agregarle un comentario del tipo

> Estaba empezando a responder esto pero eliminaron la pregunta y quise compartirlo de todas formas.

Answer (score 1):

Es claro que la pregunta en el título es una pregunta retórica y lo que nos has externado es tu molestia.

La "buena" noticia es que las publicaciones eliminadas todavía están accesibles, la "mala" noticia es que se requiere de una reputación alta para poder verlas.

Otra "buena" noticia es que no eres la única a la que le ha pasado ni la única que encuentra esto molesto. La "mala" noticia es que no se ve que se vaya a hacer algo al respecto pronto (al menos no he encontrado algo donde se diga lo contrario)

Relacionado

[Habilitar a usuarios con rep < 2000 ver respuestas propias que fueron eliminadas por la eliminación de la pregunta por su autor](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1413/65)

Preguntas similares en Stack Exchange Meta (mas recientes primero)

- [May I suggest: Are you sure you want to delete? Someone's answering the question right now. Give them 5 minutes to finish](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114170/289691)
- [Starting to answer a question should lock it for a minute so that answer can be completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95715/289691)
- [When answering, could we be informed that "the following people are already answering this question"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/35291/289691)
- ["User X is writing an answer" - banner to appear when another user is writing too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11263/289691)

Comment: Buen trabajo encontrando la primera de MSE (no era fácil)!... Las otras 3 me parece que van a algo completamente diferente (avisarle a otro que responda, no a quien pregunta).

Comment: @Mariano : Gracias. Las últimas tres no tienen una relación del todo directa pero me que deben se conocer al hacer un "feature-request" para que resulte completo al menos para señalar traslapes o bien diferenciar una petición de las otras :)